# Reading a resource XML file in Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing, android-resources

There are many examples on how to parse and read XML files, but so far, I've not found one with the Android resource format XML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <string name="form_submit">Submit</string>
        <string name="form_abort">Cancel</string>
        <string name="form_reset">Clear</string>
    </resources>
```

1. How do I read such an XML file into a Javascript variable?
2. How do I read the values *(Submit, Cancel, Clear)* using their corresponding keys, *(form_submit, form_abort, form_reset)?*

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: *"There are many examples on how to parse and read XML files"* How is it any different? XML is XML?

Comment: @epascarello None that I could find demonstrate accessing the values by their corresponding key. *Do you know how?*

Comment: How are you reading the XML file, loading from an HTTP endpoint?

Comment: @MadsHansen The XML source would be a local file. But I'm not sure how to load it and parse it to get the key-pair values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [DOMParser()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) and  [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```
var submit,abort,reset;
var text = '<resources><string name="form_submit">Submit</string><string name="form_abort">Cancel</string><string name="form_reset">Clear</string></resources>';

parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");

submit = xmlDoc.querySelectorAll("string[name='form_submit']")[0].innerHTML;
abort = xmlDoc.querySelectorAll("string[name='form_abort']")[0].innerHTML;
reset = xmlDoc.querySelectorAll("string[name='form_reset']")[0].innerHTML;
```

Comment: Wow! That's great. And simple too. Thank you so much. If the source XML is in a local file, what would be the best way to read it into a Javascript variable?

Comment: There are browser security restrictions that usually prevent arbitrarily reading files from the filesystem, but there may be options depending how you expect the file to be selected i.e. `<input type="file"/>` or if your browser supports the File API: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript